# Custom form values in hook_form_alter() not available in custom validate function

Tags: 7, forms

I'm modyfing a node form to add a few extra fields. On submit, I need to program some extra logic to these values then save them to the node object.

```
function module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'my_node_form') {
    $form['custom_form'] = array(
     '#type' => 'textfield',
     '#title' => t('Custom field'),
     '#default_value' => 'enter custom text here',
    );

    $form['#validate'][] = 'custom_form_process_values';  
  }
 }


 function custom_form_process_values(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    echo '<pre>' . print_r($form_id,1) . '</pre>';
    echo '<pre>' . print_r($form_state,1) . '</pre>';
    exit();
  }
```

When I go to node/22/edit and change "enter custom text here" to something else, and I submit the form, I only ever see "enter custom text here" and not the new text I entered. It seems that it does not carry the text through to the validate function. Also tried it in a submit function but the same problem occurs.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

This pair of functions should do the trick:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if (stripos($form_id, 'node_form') !== FALSE) {
    $form['custom_form'] = array(
     '#type' => 'textfield',
     '#title' => t('Custom field'),
     '#default_value' => 'enter custom text here',
    );
    $form['#validate'][] = 'mymodule_custom_form_process_values';
  }
 }

function mymodule_custom_form_process_values($form, &$form_state) {
  // Check to see if the default text has been altered by the user.
  if ($form_state['values']['custom_form'] != $form['custom_form']['#default_value']) {
    // Do something here...
  }
}
```

Tested on Drupal 7.53.